# How to make my linear probe hash function more efficient?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

I am struggling here to see if my linear probing technique is correct and if it is efficient at all. Is there any way for me to make it more efficient?

```
static void enterValues(int values[], int hashTable[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        int k = hashFunction(values[i]);
        if(hashTable[k]== 0)
        hashTable[k] = values[i];
        else{
            boolean b = false;
            int counter = k%hashTable.length+1;
            if(counter >= hashTable.length)
                counter = 0;
                while (!b) {
                    if (hashTable[counter] == 0) {
                        hashTable[counter] = values[i];
                        b = true;
                    } else {
                        counter = counter % hashTable.length+1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

static int hashFunction(int value)
{
    return value % 10;
}

int values[] = {4371,1323,6173,4199,4344,9679,1989};
```

the output for the size 10 hashset is

```
9679,
4371,
1989,
1323,
6173,
4344,
0,
0,
0,
4199
```

Thank you for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

Why your hash function just returns `value % 10`? It's better to return `value % hashTable.length`. I'd suggest you to use [Integer.hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode--) and then do a modulus with `hashTable.length`

```
int counter = k%hashTable.length+1;
if(counter >= hashTable.length)
    counter = 0;
```

These two statements can be replaced by: `int counter = k % hashTable.length`

To make it more efficient you can have additional book-keeping where you store the unfilled indices in hash table, and while filling you query this unfilled array (or a better data-structure - which can be sorted-tree to make searching, insertion and deletion faster) when you have clashes.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect.  Consider what happens if `value[i]` is zero:

```
   if (hashTable[k] == 0) {
        hashTable[k] = values[i];
   } else { .... }
```

Since you are using zero in the hashtable to mean that the entry is not used, and you are also assigning values directly into the table, your code cannot distinguish a zero value from an empty entry.